# Why does my preflight request return 400 for an http DELETE with body made using axios in firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, axios, aws-api-gateway

I have an issue where the preflight request of an axios DELETE request with body in firefox results in a 400 status code.

I have checked other OPTIONS requests to the same api and all respond successfully. I have tried performing the request in other browsers like Chrome, Safari, and Edge, and the only one that performs the request successfully is Chrome.I have tried changing to another network and the problem persists.

The API is hosted on AWS API Gateway where an OPTIONS /{proxy+} is configured as a mock.

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some.url',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
const response = await instance.delete('/path/to/endpoint', {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'some authorization token',
    },
    data: {
        message: 'some message',
    },
});
```

I expect the output to be an HTTP 200 status code, but the actual output is a 400 status code.